# Boto keeps crashing in ssl.c

Tags: python, ssl, boto

Once every 3 connections (roughly) boto crashes when we try to open a connection.

I've printed all the parameters just before it leaves python and on every connection the parameters are the same.

Here's the stack trace:

```
boto/sqs/connection.pyc in get_queue(self, queue_name)
    292         :returns: The requested queue, or ``None`` if no match was found.
    293         """
--> 294         rs = self.get_all_queues(queue_name)
    295         for q in rs:
    296             if q.url.endswith(queue_name):

boto/sqs/connection.pyc in get_all_queues(self, prefix)
    281         if prefix:
    282             params['QueueNamePrefix'] = prefix
--> 283         return self.get_list('ListQueues', params, [('QueueUrl', Queue)])
    284 
    285     def get_queue(self, queue_name):

boto/connection.pyc in get_list(self, action, params, markers, path, parent, verb)
    880         if not parent:
    881             parent = self
--> 882         response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)
    883         body = response.read()
    884         boto.log.debug(body)

boto/connection.pyc in make_request(self, action, params, path, verb)
    866         if self.APIVersion:
    867             http_request.params['Version'] = self.APIVersion
--> 868         return self._mexe(http_request)
    869 
    870     def build_list_params(self, params, items, label):

boto/connection.pyc in _mexe(self, request, sender, override_num_retries, retry_handler)
    792             raise BotoServerError(response.status, response.reason, body)
    793         elif e:
--> 794             raise e
    795         else:
    796             msg = 'Please report this exception as a Boto Issue!'

SSLError: _ssl.c:316: Invalid SSL protocol variant specified.
```

Here is the relevant C code:

```
PySSL_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_TLS1)
    self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method()); /* Set up context */
else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL3)
    self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method()); /* Set up context */
else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL2)
    self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_method()); /* Set up context */
else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL23)
    self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method()); /* Set up context */
PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS

if (self->ctx == NULL) {
    errstr = ERRSTR("Invalid SSL protocol variant specified.");
    goto fail;
}
```

We've printed the `proto_version` and it always `PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL23`, I think that `SSL_CTX_new` fails for some reason.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: can You, Sir, write `boto`'s version and couple more line from `connetions.pyc` ?

Comment: We're running boto 2.3.0, same error with 2.8.0. I'm starting to think this might be openssl that's broken. It's hard getting a stack track for the remaining, the last function in python is `ssl.wrap_socket`

Comment: Please, Sir, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484265/320104 maybe this will help

Comment: We most definitely don't want to disable SSL verification.

Comment: But I want You to look for `verify` parameter. Can You sniffe (using for example `Wireshark` exacly URL You are hitting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was due to one of our certificates we load is probably bad in some way, weird why it's not crashing every time though.

Anyway, removing the cert solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

some issue with certifi latest version so downgrading certifi will solve issue

```
pip uninstall -y certifi && pip install certifi==2015.04.28

                            or 

pip install requests[security]
```